# How do I learn to run games in the OSR/old school D&D “Way”, as an experienced 3e/5e DM?

Tags: osr

I'm a seasoned D&D 3e/5e DM, and I'm interested in learning how to run an old-school game. The trouble is, the 3e/5e "way" is trained into me (e.g. I'm very used to calling for skill checks to resolve things, I am used to characters having mechanical actions to take in combat other than their normal attacks, etc.). I'm concerned that if I don't shift my thinking a little bit, I will make the system feel boring and restrictive to my players.

**How do I learn to run a successful old-school style game for my friends who are also used to later editions?**

The appeal of the whole old school thing, to me, is the simplicity of it. I figure that having fewer rules than 3e and 5e might speed things up and also encourage a more immersive and less "gamey-feeling" playing experience. I'm not tied down to any particular OSR system, but Swords & Wizardry and Lamentations of the Flame Princess both have piqued my interest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like the definition of OSR gaming presented by Matthew Finch in "[A Primer For Old School Gaming](http://www.lulu.com/content/3019374)," available in pdf for free from Lulu.

In short, he refers to four major conceits ("Zen Moments") that define old school gaming.

- Rulings, Not Rules - GM-driven world interpretation over a law degree
- Player Skill, not Character Abilities
- Heroic, not Superhero - even early supers games tended to be gritty in execution
- Forget “Game Balance”

A related statement to the Game Balance part is old school presenting combat as war instead of as a "balanced" sport - see [Combat as Sport vs. Combat as War: a Key Difference in D&D Play Styles](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?317715-Very-Long-Combat-as-Sport-vs-Combat-as-War-a-Key-Difference-in-D-amp-D-Play-Styles) on ENWorld.

Another viewpoint in the [Old School Role-Playing Games](http://rpgtalk.wikia.com/wiki/Old_school_role-playing_games) entry on rpgtalk.wikia.com brings out four other aspects:

- Simulation focused gameplay
- Strong central narrative
- Garage production values - this is the retro/nostalgia aspect
- Lack of conventional wisdom - more unique trailblazers not worried about what "people say"

When I went back and ran some 2e after running 3e+ for a while, I found it very refreshing - full writeup at https://geek-related.com/2009/05/03/some-thoughts-on-2e-and-3e/ but it absolutely helped immersion and game speed.

As with learning to do anything - watch some on YouTube, try to play in one at a con or something to get the feel, then just do it.  The more stripped down rulesets will be somewhat of a forcing factor, and you'll just also have to be explicit about the assumptions (give them the Primer) and iterate into it.  There will be some frustration about not having so many "buttons to push," but if you make it clear that there's actually infinitely more buttons because you can do anything, not only things on your character sheet, you'll get there.

Comment: The "Primer" is still a pretty good text for laying out the principles better than sifting through blogposts can, but the actual examples in it are _so bad_.

Comment: I found that running a system specifically designed for OSR-style play (Adventurer Conquerer King) *really* helped me get the hang of the whole thing.